# Converting string to float - python

Tags: python, pandas, string, null, type-conversion

How can I convert one string column to float considering that it contains N/A values?
I've tried to use the to_numeric function, but I'm receiving an error: "Unable to parse string "N/A" at position.

Comment: Are you talking about a column in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Use an if condition. Check if the value is not NA then do the conversion.

Comment: if pandas, something like: `np.where(df["your column"].isna() is False, df["your column"], df["your column"].astype(float))`

Comment: Yes, pandas. I've tried this code, but it also results in an error "could not convert string to float: 'N/A'

Comment: oh it's a string, then just: `df["your column"].replace("N/A", np.nan).astype(float)`

Comment: Unfortunately still not.. It doesn't return an error. However, after checking the type of my column it's still string and I still cannot perform any calculations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution that worked in my case was to add an argument errors='coerce' to the to_numeric function.

`df["mycolumn"] = pd.to_numeric(df["mycolumn"], errors='coerce', downcast="float")`